# AJAX function not running php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an icon in my html code which calls an ajax function when it's clicked

HTML:

```
 <i id="9" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x pull-right"></i>
```

Jquery & AJAX :

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
$(".fa-star-o").click(function(){
    fieldId= this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: {fieldId: fieldId},
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 'true'){}
        }
    }); 
});
```

The issue is that this is not running the php file (edit.php)

Edit: I have multiple icons in the page with the class fa-star-o, don't know if this is a problem

EDIT(SOLVED): Looks like in my php file I had a typo getting the $_POST variables (UserId instead of userId), the only way I was able to see the error was to do as Mahesh said and do a console.log(response) after the success.

Comment: check the console to find errors

Comment: How do you know the PHP files isn't run? Are you *sure*?

Comment: No errors in console

Comment: And you spelled "success" wrong, so the callback won't be properly attached.

Comment: I know the PHP file isn't running because i've tried to put a simple javascript alert in the php file and nothing poped up but if I manually inserted the url I got the alert

Comment: That is why you should add an error handler to your ajax calls since they will not always be successful

Answer (score 1):

Try querying this way:

```
$.post('/edit.php', { data: {fieldId: fieldId} }, function(result) {
    ...
});
```

Look what comes in response.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @rafael-duarte Try to refer to element ID. As you said, you can have several elements with a class "fa-star-o".

Comment: Thing is i'm loading multiple icons dynamically and I would have to create a function for each one of them, but I've tried to see the id it is getting in the console using console.log(fieldId) and it's getting the right one.

Comment: @rafael-duarte Try as I write above

Comment: It's solved, I had a typo in my php file (see my last edit)